# C++ Scope of Pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, scope

I have a question
For example I have code below:

```
void function1()
{
    Car car;
    car.color = 10;
    carPtr = &car;
    std::cout << carPtr->color;
}

void function2()
{
    std::cout << carPtr->color;
}

int main()
{
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

This code for some odd reason works.
If I created a instance of car in the scope of function1() then why am I able to use car in function2()???
Should'nt have carPtr pointed to nullptr the moment it left function1() because car exists in the scope of function1()
is the data for the "car" object being copied into function2() and how would that work??? Can someone explain what is going on please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code as posted cannot possibly work. There are no include files to bring `std::cout` to the party, nor is there any declaration of `carPtr` or `Car`. This code cannot compile much less work. Assuming `carPtr` is some global `Car *` you're invoking undefined behavior, which means the code is broken primal. Undefined behavior means it may appear to work, it may not, it may literally do *anything*, and that includes *nothing*. The program is ill-formed. You're confusing *observed* behavior with *defined* behavior. The latter leads to the former, the former is *not* a guarantee of the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Every function has its own stack frame in the stack. So when you bind address of `car` to `carPtr`, `carPtr` is a pointer to an address in stack frame of function1. Then function1 exits, the stack frame will be recycled (usually adding stack pointer). The address of function1 stack frame maybe reuse when function2 executes. So value of `car` **may** be corrupted because of execution of function2. Above code will cause undefined behavior. changing environment of execution may change output of this program.

> Should'nt have carPtr pointed to nullptr the moment it left function1()

No, carPtr will always point to this address unless you change it explicitly. Only difference is whether the address is legal.